# creating url from loop - variable syntax

Tags: php, sql

Hi guys I am trying to create a url from a looping SQL statement, where the count is greater than 70.

```
// SQL QUERY TO GET CATEGORY COUNT
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(domains.domain) c, domains.category_id, 
         categories.category_description
         FROM categories INNER JOIN domains ON categories.category_id = 
         domains.category_id
         GROUP BY categories.category_id
         ORDER BY c DESC";

$results = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);           
if (!$results){     
    //Output error message if query execution failed
    die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error()); 
} 

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($results);

// START PRINTING
print '<div class="readableTable">';

if ($rows) {     

    //START LOOP
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

        if ($row["c"] > 70){

            $theId = $row["category_id"];  // DIDN'T WORK!

            // URL CAUSING ISSUE 
            <a href="category_25.php?category_id=$row["category_id"]">

            // print '<div class="readable">'.$row["c"].'</div>';
            print '<div class="readable">'
                   .$row["category_description"]
                   .'('.$row["c"]
                   .')</a></div>';

        }
    }
}
```

So you can see I am trying to create the url based on the category id.

But I can't extract the correct category_id to put into the url.

Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comments `DIDN'T WORK` and `URL CAUSING ISSUE`?  Also, a var_dump of your `$row` variables and current output are going to be necessary

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the only problem, but one issue is that the string you're printing is quoted with `'` instead of `"`, so `$row["category_id"]` will not be [interpreted as a variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

```
print '<div class="readable">

// URL CAUSING ISSUE 
<a href="category_25.php?category_id=$row["category_id"]">

'.$row["category_description"].
'('.$row["c"].
')</a>
</div>';
```

If you want to use the variable in the string like that, the main string needs to be quoted with `"`, and the array key should not be quoted. If you change the outer quotes to `"`, any quotes like that inside the string will need to be either escaped or changed to `'` (It's usually fine to use `'` to quote HTML attribute values.).

```
print "<div class=\"readable\">

// URL CAUSING ISSUE 
<a href=\"category_25.php?category_id=$row[category_id]\">

".$row["category_description"].
'('.$row["c"].
')</a>
</div>';
```

Alternatively, you could just concatenate `$row['category_id']` like you're doing with the other variables. I would suggest choosing either variable interpolation or concatenation, and using that for *all* of the variables you're using in this string. Building your string in a consistent way will make your code more readable.

For example, switching to all variable interpolation:

```
print "<div class='readable'>
    <a href='category_25.php?category_id=$row[category_id]'>
       $row[category_description] ($row[c])
    </a>
</div>";
```

Comment: Thank you -- I will try not to panic in the morning when I try this!